# executing JS functions from a Phonegap Android Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm making a **Phonegap Android app** using **Phonegap v1.3**. I wrote a plugin for phonegap which gets a particular file from the system and then executes a js function. 

 As all plugins extend the Phonegap class  **Plugin**, i can't execute a js function directly from there. so from the **execute**  function of the Plugin, i execute  -->

```
PluginResult result = null;
Home home = new Home();
result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
home.loadPage("pic.jpg");
```

In this the Home is my main class which extends **Droidgap.**  
In home i have the function **loadPage**

```
public void loadPage(String filePath){   
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
super.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.somefunc(\""+filePath+"\");");  
}
```

The problem is that the  **setIntegerProperty** function of DroidGap is throwing an NPE. Here are the logs.

```
01-16 11:41:32.364: W/System.err(13162): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 11:41:32.364: W/System.err(13162):    at com.phonegap.DroidGap.setIntegerProperty(DroidGap.java:738)
01-16 11:41:32.364: W/System.err(13162):    at e2o.mobile.Home.loadSharePage(Home.java:120)
01-16 11:41:32.364: W/System.err(13162):    at com.phonegap.plugins.checkImage.CheckUploadImage.execute(CheckUploadImage.java:158)
01-16 11:41:32.364: W/System.err(13162):    at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:150)
01-16 11:41:32.364: W/System.err(13162):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Bascically in the setIntegerProperty function -

```
public void setIntegerProperty(String name, int value) {
    this.getIntent().putExtra(name, value);
}
```

the **this.getIntent()** is returning null. **can u pls tell me what am i missing. Or in my use case scenario, how do i execute that js function.** If i dont use

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000, intent);
```

then also the loadUrl does nothing. the JS does not get called, or it times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are instantiating a new Home object. The object is created using the constructor but the onCreate method is not called so a lot of the proper object setup doesn't occur. That is why you are getting the NullPointerException.

You are returning a new PluginResult with a status of OK so the success function of the can execute the navigator.somefunc(filePath) method for you. It'll be a lot easier that way.

Comment: yes i was following a wrong approach. success function should execute the js function. works fine now.  :)